# Detect Crop Lines using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am working on a lane detection project and I want to feed in the path robot can take between crop rows.  I initially converted the image to birds eye view for better processing and tried Hough transform, but Hough transform is not giving me good results.

## Bird's eye view of the image

[image: Birds eye view of the image]

Are there any other approaches I am missing out?

Comment: (1) Show us what you've tried.  (2) What are the output results you are getting?  (3) What are the **expected** results?

Answer (score 0):

Before applying the Hough lines algorithm you could do the following :

1)Color shifting

Apply color shifting where you split the colors of the image into blue, green and red channels. Since the crop rows are green you can amplify the color green to stand out more from the rest of the channels

```
b,g,r = cv2.split(img) 
gscale = 2*g-r-b
```

2)Canny Edge Detection

Fiddle with the min and max arguments in the cv2.Canny() function until satisfactory.

```
gscale = cv2.Canny(gscale,minVal,maxValue)
```

3)Skeletonization

Skeletonization is the process of thinning the regions of interest to their binary constituents. This makes it easier for to perform pattern recognition.

```
size = np.size(gscale) #returns the product of the array dimensions
skel = np.zeros(gscale.shape,np.uint8) #array of zeros
ret,gscale = cv2.threshold(gscale,128,255,0) #thresholding the image
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
done = False
while( not done):
    eroded = cv2.erode(gscale,element)
    temp = cv2.dilate(eroded,element)
    temp = cv2.subtract(gscale,temp)
    skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel,temp)
    gscale = eroded.copy()
zeros = size - cv2.countNonZero(gscale)
    if zeros==size:
        done = True
```

You should get better performance in the Hough lines algorithm after applying all these in their respective order.